# How do you exclude files with a suffix in a batch file rename?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to exclude any file with "Confidential" in the name from being renamed by this script which batch renames files in a folder.

However, when I try this script the file names with "Confidential" in it don't change, nor do the ones without "Confidential" in it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude "*Confidential*"  | rename-item -NewName { $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" +$_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the absence of `-Recurse`, the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters apply only to the leaf component (file/directory name) of the *input path* (the current dir., in your case), not to those its *children*.

The workaround is to use `Get-Item *` (or `Get-ChildItem *`) instead. which ensures that the (implied) target path's *children* are targeted (with an explicit target path, *append* `/*`; add `-Force` to include *hidden* children), which in turn ensures that any `-Include` / `-Exclude` arguments are applied to the names of those children:

```
Get-Item * -Exclude *Confidential*  | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" + $_.Extension }
```

See [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304) for a discussion.